# Semantic Segmentation on computer vision - Output value

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I'm new to Semantic Segmentation and I'm having a problem.

I have the 'imgs_3d' and 'segmentation' list that are the images we'll use for training.

`X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(imgs_3d, segmentation, train_size=0.8, random_state=0)`

When I apply `np.array(X_train).shape` and `np.array(y_train).shape` we have the following result for both: `(598, 1024, 2041, 3)`.

My intention is to train a simple cnn model just to know more about the methods, and then apply U-net.

What I have in mind is: "Train the model with the normal imgs and the img segmentation, then on X put normal images and y the img segmentation. Now it's just to train and have the output value as being the img segmentated"

But when I try to do it:

```
model = 

Sequential([Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', input_shape=(1024, 2041, 3)),

MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3)),

])

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy']
)

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5, verbose=1)
```

I get the error `ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 1024 and 341 for '{{node binary_crossentropy/mul}} = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT](binary_crossentropy/Cast, binary_crossentropy/Log)' with input shapes: [?,1024,2041,3], [?,341,680,32].`

I don't know why this is happening. Please, help me (with details if possible)! Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues in your code:

**1. Model output**

Your provided model architecture is as follows:

```
model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', input_shape=(1024, 2041, 3)),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3)),
])
```

The input shape is `(1024, 2041, 3)`. After passing through the `Conv2D`, the shape becomes `(1024, 2041, 32)`. After passing the `MaxPooling2D`, the shape is divided by 3, so model output is `(341, 680, 32)`. This output shape doesn't match your segmentation task requirements, so it results the error messages.

In segmentation tasks, the model output should have the same shape as `y_train`. For example, if the shape of `y_train` is `(1024, 2041, 20)`, your model's output shape should be equal to `(1024, 2041, 20)`.

**2. Loss Function**

You seem to be training a multi-class segmentation model, so you should use `categorical_crossentropy` instead of `binary_crossentropy`.

Here I write a very simple example.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
model = keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=5, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', input_shape=(1024, 2041, 3)),])
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
X_train = tf.random.normal([8, 1024, 2041, 3])
y_train = tf.random.normal([8, 1024, 2041, 5])
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5, verbose=1)
```

In this example, the shape of `y_train` is `(1024, 2041, 5)`, so the model architecture is designed to produce an output with the same shape as `y_train`. Additionally, `categorical_crossentropy` is used for training the model.

For medical image segmentation tasks, we would consider more complex architectures like **U-Net**. If you encounter further issues with the model architecture, you can refer to GitHub repositories that focus on medical image segmentation.